# MS Graph API Onenote page create/update request size limit

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, onenote, onenote-api, microsoft-graph-onenote

According to the first item of [limitations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/onenote-images-files#size-limitations-for-post-pages-requests) we can't upload files bigger than 4 Mb to OneNote page via [create](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/section-post-pages?view=graph-rest-1.0#example) or [update](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/onenote-update-page#multipart-request-with-binary-content) page request (using multipart request). But using UI we can upload such or even larger files to OneNote page.

Is there some approach or workaround to upload files bigger than 4 Mb to OneNote page using Graph API (or something else)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The limit is 4MB for Graph API but as noted at the link you provided the OneNote API has a 70MB limit. It uses the basic same structure as the Graph API except a different URL

```
POST https://www.onenote.com/api/v1.0/me/notes/sections/{id}/pages
```

vs

```
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/onenote/sections/{id}/pages
```